# How to make group box text alignment center in win forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a group box and there are several controls inside this.

My requirement is to set the group box title to the middle of the group box instead of Left.

How?

Comment: @Harry, I think he is referring to groupbox's title? Is it?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I thought it covered some material to centre controls in the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can extend the group box class like this.

```
 public class CustomGrpBox : GroupBox
    {
        private string _Text = "";
        public CustomGrpBox()
        {
            //set the base text to empty 
            //base class will draw empty string
            //in such way we see only text what we draw
            base.Text = "";
        }
        //create a new property a
        [Browsable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("GroupBoxText")]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
        public new string Text
        {
            get
            {

                return _Text;
            }
            set
            {

                _Text = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {

              //first let the base class to draw the control 
              base.OnPaint(e);
              //create a brush with fore color
              SolidBrush colorBrush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);
              //create a brush with back color
              var backColor = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor);
              //measure the text size
              var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(this.Text, this.Font);
              // evaluate the postiong of text from left;
              int left = (this.Width - size.Width) / 2;
              //draw a fill rectangle in order to remove the border
              e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColor, new Rectangle(left, 0, size.Width, size.Height));
              //draw the text Now
              e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, colorBrush, new PointF(left, 0));

        }
    }
```

add the above class into your project and use "CustomGrpBox" instead of "GroupBox" which will be created after build in your tool box.

and you can set the text any time like this.

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        customGrpBox1.Text = "Hello World";
    }
```

[image: it will look like this in design time visual studio]

it will look like this in design time visual studio

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, you may set the title on the right by using the RightToLeft property, but there is no property to set it in the middle.

What you can do is to set an empty Text in your GroupBox, create a Label with the title and put that label above the GroupBox (with the same parent).

You may do it dynamically at form initialization by calling following procedure:

```
private void CenterGroupBoxTitle(GroupBox groupbox)
{
  Label label   = new Label() ;
  label.Text    = groupbox.Text ;
  groupbox.Text = "" ;
  label.Left    = groupbox.Left+(groupbox.Width-label.Width)/2 ;
  label.Top     = groupbox.Top + 2 ; // 2 is an example : adjust the constant
  label.Parent  = groupbox.Parent ;
  label.BringToFront() ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a custom control using `Panel` as container and draw border around this, you can then have full control of the title's alignment.

If you would like a simple approach, you can leave the groupbox's title as empty text, and then place a `label` at the center position of the groupbox. You can also define this as user-control so you wouldn't need to do this repeatedly.

Comment: Extending the groupbox  and repainting the label to the desired location is the simpliest way to go as other answerer posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Not an eloquent solution, but if you have a simple GroupBox, that stays the( same size, you can just pad the beginning, and the end with spaces.

example : `GroupBox.Text = "       This is the groupbox text       ";`

The amount of padding of space's will depend on the length of the box.
Of course you'll lose some of the GroupBox's beginning and end lines on top, and if that's important, then Answer 3 seems like a good solution.