# How to find out the left margin of the title in a groupbox

Tags: c#, winforms, groupbox

I have an a form that has groupboxes and textfields with a label above the textfields. But I hate that the titles are not all on the same line. Those few pixels bother me.
[image]
I'd like to move the titles above the textboxes a little to the right so that they're on the same width as the titles in the groupbox. But for that I need to know the length of the indent the groupbox adds, so the length of the red line in the image. Is there any way to get that?

I already have an alternative. I could create my own groupbox with an indent I know and control as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827366/how-to-make-group-box-text-alignment-center-in-win-forms). But I'm hoping for a better solution.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/GroupBoxRenderer.cs,167